# How to convert 2D surface area into 3D surface area using DEM

Tags: qgis, dem, convert

I have a polygon layer of the area burned by wildfire, which lies in the very hilly terrain. The polygon of the burned area was drawn manually over the ortophoto, which means, that the polygon has only 2 dimension. Is it possible to convert the 2D area information to 3D area information using for example DEM in QGIS ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to GIS SE. You should chose one tool to pick up from  (QGIS / Arcgis) for your question to remain open. What kind of additional information would you want and in which format(raster, vector) ? Is it the surface area that you need to compute more accurately ?

Comment: You may still need the flat area for some analysis. The rain falls vertically, the plants grow vertically as well and they don't get advantage from the extra area.

Comment: "Is it possible" Questions ask the wrong question -- What you really want to know is "**How** is it possible ..." You should also give an indication of what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Thank you, @Kasper . I have chosen QGIS for the analyses. I don´t  need any specific data fomat. I need only the surface area, as you wrote.

Comment: In QGIS you can run the `r.surf.area` in Processing Toolbox/GRASS. Make sure the you are using a CRS in meters and DEM height in meters, it will return the total surface area of the DEM whithin the extent of Polygon (select polygon as region extent)